# TF31002 error when cloning all history from Azure DevOps TFVC collection to Git with GIT-TFS tool

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, git-tfs

I am trying to migrate a project from Azure DevOps TFVC to Azure DevOps Git with all changeset history, not only for the last 180 days. Just in case, I have migrated the changes of the last 180 days with the tool included in Azure DevOps. So now I have 2 repositories en this project:

- TFVC collection with {collection-name}
- Git repository with another name.

[I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861859/move-some-projects-from-a-user-account-to-another) and I am stuck in "Clone the repository to a local folder" step. I have Git installed and downloaded the [latest realease of GIT-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases) tool.

I have a Personal and Professional account on Azure DevOps with `{email-account}`. The project I want to migrate is in the Personal account. I am running this command following [this official help](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#fetch-all-the-history-for-just-the-main-branch-ignoring-all-the-other-branches):

`git tfs clone -u {email-account} -p {personal-account-password} https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}/ $/{folder-name}/ . --branches=none`

I get `{collection-name}` and `{folder-name}` from Visual Studio 2017 Pro when I tried to connect to the remote collection. I have only this version of VS. After running the command I get this output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/DATA/Git/.git/

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.
Team Foundation Server Url: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
All the logs could be found in the log file: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt
```

And if it helps, here is log file content:

```
2019-03-04 11:42:17.4562 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0
2019-03-04 11:42:17.4816 [Debug] Visual Studio 2015 detected...
2019-03-04 11:42:17.6387 [Debug] git command: Starting process: git rev-parse --show-prefix
2019-03-04 11:42:17.6744 [Debug] git stderr: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
2019-03-04 11:42:17.6744 [Debug] git command time: [00:00:00.0396901] rev-parse --show-prefix
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7083 [Debug] Command run:git tfs clone -u {email-account} -p {personal-account-password} https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name} $/{folder-name} . --branches=none
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7083 [Debug] No authors file used.
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7083 [Debug] git-tfs version 0.29.0.0 (TFS client library 14.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Looking for assembly StructureMap.resources, Version=2.6.1.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223 ...
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\WDExpress\14.0_Config|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\14.0_Config|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Looking for assembly StructureMap.resources, Version=2.6.1.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223 ...
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\WDExpress\14.0_Config|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] Trying to get HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\14.0_Config|InstallDir
2019-03-04 11:42:17.7379 [Debug] git command: Starting process: git init
2019-03-04 11:42:17.8112 [Info] Initialized empty Git repository in C:/DATA/Git/.git/

2019-03-04 11:42:17.8252 [Debug] git command time: [00:00:00.0767692] init
2019-03-04 11:42:17.8481 [Debug] No .gitignore file specified...
2019-03-04 11:42:18.9405 [Debug] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.
Team Foundation Server Url: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()
   at GitTfs.VsCommon.TfsHelperBase.EnsureAuthenticated()
   at GitTfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.EnsureTfsAuthenticated()
   at GitTfs.Core.GitRepository.CreateTfsRemote(RemoteInfo remote, String autocrlf, String ignorecase)
   at GitTfs.Commands.Init.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath)
   at GitTfs.Commands.Init.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath, String gitRepositoryPath)
   at GitTfs.Commands.Clone.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath, String gitRepositoryPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at GitTfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 args)
   at GitTfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 unparsedArgs)
   at GitTfs.GitTfs.Run(IList`1 args)
   at GitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args)
2019-03-04 11:42:18.9635 [Error] TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.
Team Foundation Server Url: https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/{collection-name}.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2019-03-04 11:42:18.9635 [Error] The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2019-03-04 11:42:18.9734 [Warn] All the logs could be found in the log file: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt
```

Comment: I don't remember if Azure changes something from the early age of git support or if you should still use https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/TF400813-error-with-visualstudio.com.md I also hope your collection name is set to `DefaultCollection`. And you could also try to not specify login and password and a popup will open to enter your credentials and that should do it...

Comment: Thank you, you give me the key. I don't know why, the project's collection name I can see on DevOps or VS is different from DefaultCollection. Setting this collection name I did some successful migrations. First enabling alternate authentication credentials and using the -u username -p password pattern, but I had to login on a popup window. After that, history download started. In another test I have disabled alternate authentication credentials, and without specifying -u and -p parameters and without popup, the download started. Did the credentials be saved somewhere the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clone a TFVC repository on Azure DevOps, you should:

- Enable alternate credentials. Go to "My profile"->"Security"-> Enter data and "Enable alternate credentials"
- use the command following this pattern (where 'yourLogin' and 'yourPassword' was defined in the previous step)
  `git tfs clone https://dev.azure.com/{organization} $/project/folder  --username=yourLogin --password=yourPassword`

[image]

To succeed, visualstudio.com needs (for authentication) that you use the TFS2012 version of the TFS dlls. Otherwise, you will see the message :

`TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required`

To be sure that git-tfs uses this version, use the command `git tfs --version` and you should see the text `TFS client library 11.0.0.0`, like in:

`git-tfs version 0.17.2.0 (TFS client library 11.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)`

Comment: you could force git-tfs to use a specific version of the tfs assemblies (See https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/57a37c2a39b2e774419c36059cb82267a4d1c051/doc/troubleshooting-checkin-policies.md#git-tfs-should-be-using-the-same-version-of-visual-studio-that-you-are ) by setting an environment variable (but that will require to have this version of Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I managed to migrate all history using "DefaultCollection" in collection name (instead of the name I can read on DevOps project): git tfs clone -u {email-account} -p {personal-account-password} https://{devops-username}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection $/{folder-name}/ . --branches=none

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with this: `git tfs clone https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName} $/{Project}/{Branch} ./`